# How can I protect files in a folder in a PHP site?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP. What I need is to protect the folder files from listing the file names when we enter the path for the folder.

http://test.com/admin/free_tmplt

This is my folder path and when I use this path directly it display the file names. How to avoid this and display a message like "Protected page"?

Comment: What web server are you using? Is this using Apache, IIS? The answer really depends on configuring your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `.htacess` file in the folder and type in `deny from all`.

Answer (score 1):

To just stop them from being listed (this is not going to secure the files.. but this is the question you asked) just simply create index.php in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it so all files within that folder have randomized filenames that are changed at regular intervals, when people load certain pages, etc. (and these ever-changing filenames would be stored in a DB) - This way no one could "guess" or directly link to files, regardless of whether they're hidden or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file called (index.php) and put it in every folder you want to hide its contents (prevent them from being listed), and put the next line of code in that (index.php) file:

```
<?php header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); ?>
```

as this line of code will redirect the user to homepage of the website.